# How to make a dynamic button work on javascript?

Tags: javascript, button, dynamic, onclick

I have 3 buttons that works as tabs, I want to make it dynamic.

Right now I only have static text inside the onclick button. How to make it dynamic by not changing the text on each class manually? because I will add more buttons not just three

```
-- HTML --

<ul class="tab">
<li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'City One')" id="defaultOpen"><p>Food & Beverages</p></li>
<li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'City Two')"><p>Sports & Outdoors</p></li>
<li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'City Three')"><p>Furniture & Household</p></li>
</ul>

<div id="City One" class="tabcontent fade in active row">
         BODY CONTENT
</div>
<div id="City Two" class="tabcontent fade in active row">
         BODY CONTENT
</div>
<div id="City Three" class="tabcontent fade in active row">
         BODY CONTENT
</div>

-- SCRIPT --
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}
                          document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "inline-flex";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

jQuery("")
```

Comment: iterate with an array which contains your button details like city1, city2, city3...

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic. Do you want to add them when page is loaded or do you want to change them anytime while the user is on the page or do you want to change them anytime this value is changed in the server or ....

Comment: @Andam I want to change them anytime this value is changed in the server

Comment: @GlennCuatz Well good luck to get an answer about this in this question. What you need is a tutorial, book or some other reference that would teach you how to do it.